# .on does not work in place of live

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, live

I have known for a while now that .on is supposed to replace .live, however I have never been able to get it to work at all.

I have tried:

```
$(this).on('click', function(){
    // Do something...
})

$(this).on({
    click: function(){ // Do something }
})
```

But it never works for me!

Specifically when I'm trying to bind events to elements that may not exist on the page initially.

Could someone please clear this up for me once and for all?

---

I'm using the latest version of jquery.

Comment: You need to read the docs. `.on()` replaces `live`, `bind` and `delegate` and it really depends on the parameters/context what it does! By the way, `$(this).live()` is rather unlikely to work at all unless `this` was created with a `$('selector')` call.

Comment: It can be a cliche answer, but the official jQuery docs explain it really well. Have a read of the docs for the ".on()" function, specifically the parts under the "Direct and delegated events" heading. It explains how it all works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For dynamically generated elements you need to use like

```
$(document).on('click','YOUR SELECTOR', function(){

});
```

It's because document is the container of your elements which can watch changes to the DOM. For every action, there needs to be an explicit event listener. If you bind something to $(this), it (the selector) might not exist when you remove it.

Comment: However, instead of `document` he should usually use a parent element as close as possible to the newly added elements.

Comment: I just added an edit before your posted ThiefMaster ;)  but i don't see the edit now :( . Yes closest element selector is more correct in fact.

Comment: @Mahbub by nearest element do you mean nearest non-dynamically added element?

Comment: Yes of course @imperium2335 otherwise it wont work. The safest is to use document because you can't remove this element :)

Answer (score 2):

Do it like:

```
$(".parent").on('click', ".child", function(){
    // Do something...
})
```

The syntax you are using works just like `bind`. To bind event to all future elements, use above syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify *which* elements.

```
$element.on('click', '.foo', handler)
```

will bind `handler` to all live `.foo` inside `$element`.